# ¿Cómo hacer dos llamadas a dos API REST correctamente con javascript sin usar async await?

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer dos llamadas a dos api rest, en la primera con uno de los datos obtenidos, pasarlo a la segunda url y hai obtengo lo que quiero, pude lograrlo con el código de abajo pero mi jefe me dice que esta mal, primero lo hice con asyn await y me dijo que no lo usara, luego intente con axios pero que no está bien escrito, ¿cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo con axios

```
 axios.all([axios.get(`${urlRestApi}`)]).then( 
      axios.spread(response1 => {                  
        let arrPost = response1.data.map(res => {
          return {
            titulo: res.title.rendered,
            contenido: res.content.rendered,
            extracto: res.excerpt.rendered,
            idImagen: res.featured_media,
          };
        });
        console.log("AQUI", arrPost);
         arrImg = arrPost.map(image => {
          axios.get(`${urlImage}/${image.idImagen}`)
          .then(urls => {   // urls da como respuesta 10 obejetos cada uno con una imagen correspondiente
            arrUrl.push(urls.data);  //por esta razon meto los 10 en un array, pero sucede 10 veces
            if (arrUrl.length === 10) { // por eso cuando .length es 10 lo recorro y asigno lo que quiero
              let arrImage = arrUrl.map(img => {
                return {
                  imagenes: img.source_url,
                };
              });
              console.log("TEST", arrImage);
              mostrarHTML(arrImage, arrPost); //ya la tener todo ejecuto mi funcion para imprimir lo datos obtenidos
            }
          });
        });
      })
    );
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar Promises. Hacer un chain entre ellas.

Comment: Que se supone que debes hacer con el segundo llamado? consultar que? y que quieres obtener al final como resultado?